# New partitioned CouchDB document

Tags: postman, couchdb

how to create a new partitioned CouchDB document via postman (with random id)?
To create a new document you usually send it as a json format without the id, where the id gets random generated.
But how do I create a new document where I have to send the partition which will be in the id field, and still generate a random id?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but it's a good question. It may be an oversight in the documentation.